# Estimation of VAR model

Tags: time-series, self-study, estimation, vector-autoregression

Consider the following bivariate system

[image]

where $z$ and $v$ are stationary variables, $\epsilon_{zt}$ is iid (0, $\sigma_z^2$) , $\epsilon_{vt}$ is iid (0,$\sigma_v^2$) and $E(\epsilon_{zt}, \epsilon_{vt-j})=0$ for $j \ge 0$.

Under the assumption that $v_t$ contemporaneously affects $z_t$ but $z_t$ affects $v_t$ with one-period lag, obtain estimates for all unknown parameters of the original structural VAR model and discuss uniqueness of those estimates.

My attempt:

Firstly, I write VAR model in the standard form

$$z_t = \gamma_{11}^1z_{t-1}+\gamma_{12}^1v_{t-1} +\gamma_{11}^2z_{t-2} +\gamma_{12}^2 z_{t-2}+ e_{1t}$$
$$v_t = \gamma_{21}^1z_{t-1}+\gamma_{22}^1v_{t-1} +\gamma_{21}^2z_{t-2} +\gamma_{22}^2 z_{t-2}+ e_{2t}$$

In the matrix notation

$$y_t = \gamma_1 y_{t-1} +  \gamma_2 y_{t-1} +e_t$$

$$y_t = \Big( \begin{matrix} z_t \\ v_t  \end{matrix} \Big)$$
$$\gamma_1 = \Big( \begin{matrix} \gamma_{11}^1 & \gamma_{12}^1 \\ \gamma_{21}^1 & \gamma_{22}^1 \end{matrix} \Big)$$

$$\gamma_2 = \Big( \begin{matrix} \gamma_{11}^2 & \gamma_{12}^2 \\ \gamma_{21}^2 & \gamma_{22}^2 \end{matrix} \Big)$$

In order to derive the restricted version of the structural representation, apply the following transformation

$$A^{-1} = \Big( \begin{matrix} 1 & -a \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \Big)$$

Multiply both sides with $A^{-1}$

$$A^{-1} y_t = A^{-1} \gamma_1 y_{t-1} + A^{-1} \gamma_2 y_{t-1} +A^{-1}e_t$$

And obtain the version that is stated in the given assumption of the question,

$$z_t = a v_t + \phi_{11} z_{t-1} + \phi_{12} v_{t-1} + \theta_{11}z_{t-2} + \theta_{12} v_{t-2} + u_{1t} $$

$$v_t =  \phi_{21} z_{t-1} + \phi_{22} v_{t-1} + \theta_{21}z_{t-2} + \theta_{22} v_{t-2} + u_{2t} $$

So far, I have obtained the model in the given assumption, but I cannot the estimates of the parameters. How can I continue to do this question ?